# How to use data from drop down menus and two other criteria to populate a table?

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to set up a spreadsheet to summarise the amounts of money I transfer between four bank accounts. In the attached spreadsheet, I will manually put in the transfers I make between the different accounts (i.e., Everyday, Holiday, Emergency, Investments) in columns A, B, C, and D. In column A, you double-click a cell to add in a date, while columns B and C use a drop down box to choose accounts.

What I would like to do is have the information in these four columns populate the table on the right.

I've named columns B and C as "OUT" and "IN", respectively. For example, in my sheet, the second row means that on the 8th April, I'd taken $500 OUT of the Everyday account and put it IN the Holiday account.

So for the table on the right, I'd like for it to give me the totals for all the money I've transferred IN and OUT for each specific account for each specific month. Do you know what formulae I could use to do this if it's possible?

An example of my spreadsheet is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1azNw6m7f3x7WhwEP9WXolCzfTE9dccj9wjs0qPwD-FY/edit#gid=2056599600

I have tried to use `VLOOKUP` and `SUMIFS`.

Comment: whats the E column? is (should be) there a relation between those checkboxes and the table on right?

Comment: Hello, the E column has no direct relevance on the data. It's there for me to check off once I've manually put this information onto another tab so I know I've done it. For example, once I've put in the $500 into a cell where my main expenses sheet is, I can check it off. Actually, I've now realised that if this table can be populated as per my request, then there would be no need for the E column since I'll be able to reference the specific cells in that table from the other tab!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

paste this into **H3** cell and drag to the right - then drag down:

```
=IFERROR(SUM(QUERY({$A:$D}, 
 "select Col4 
  where Col"&IFS(H$2="OUT", 2, H$2="IN", 3)&"='"&IF(H$1="", G$1, H$1)&"' 
    and month(Col1)+1="&MONTH($G3&1), 0)))
```

and for totals row paste this in **H15** cell and drag to the right:

```
=SUM(H3:H14)
```

[image: 0]

**[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lnf_t2lar5BJnfNv2FDHqOhVtxCEZsXxNKel_0CVgaY/edit?usp=sharing)**

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, player0! That worked perfectly!