# How to use data from two drop down menus and two other criteria to populate a table?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I recently asked a similar question here ([How to use data from drop down menus and two other criteria to populate a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55611563/how-to-use-data-from-drop-down-menus-and-two-other-criteria-to-populate-a-table))

In that last spreadsheet, I wanted to find out how much money was going IN and OUT of each account each month. For example, I could find out that in April, I'd transferred $500 OUT of the Everyday account, but I wouldn't know how that $500 was portioned out to which accounts.

This time, I'm hoping to find out how where the money is specifically going. For example, in the attached spreadsheet, in April, I'd transferred $1000 out of the Everyday account, where $600 went into Savings and $400 went into Cash.

Might this be possible?

An example of my spreadsheet is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nSZEciOgk_t8NaMXgQM8Hw5iDTVf4ZKK7RgSJKLCtLM/edit?usp=sharing

In the attached spreadsheet, I will manually put in the transfers I make between the different accounts (i.e., Everyday, Recreation, Business, Cash, Savings, LT) in columns A, B, C, and D. In column A, you double-click a cell to add in a date, while columns B and C use a drop down box to choose accounts. In column D, I will put in the amounts.

What I would like to do is have the information in columns A, B, C, and D populate the table on the right.

I have tried using the same formula provided to me in my last question (i.e., IFERROR). However, I am not sure of how to adapt it to fit my current requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IFERROR(SUM(QUERY({$A:$D}, 
 "select Col4 
  where Col2='"&G$1&"' 
    and Col3='"&G$2&"'  
    and month(Col1)+1="&MONTH($F3&1), 0)))
```

[image: 0]

**note the filled 1st row with repeats instead of cell merge**

Comment: Thank you again for your help, player0! That worked a treat.